# Korea: Visa required to go to the city while in transit in lncheon airport for a Nepalese citizen?

Tags: transit-visas, nepali-citizens, korean-air

Hi I'm a Nepalese citizen traveling to China and have 17 hours layover in Seoul via Korean Airlines. Do I need a visa to go out of the airport for sightseeing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, according to the [embassy website](http://npl.mofa.go.kr/english/as/npl/visa/issuance/index.jsp), you need a visa. Even for 1 hour, as long as you get outside of the international zone of the airport, you will need a visa.